# Partial and full template specialization with header and source files

Tags: c++, templates

Could someone please help me refactor the following code so that it compiles (with a pre-C++11 compiler).

MyClass.h:

```
namespace myns {
enum LiteralTypes {
  kINT_LITERAL = 0,
  kSTRING_LITERAL
};

class MyClass {
  template <LiteralTypes literal_type, typename T> struct AddLiterals;

  template <typename T>
  struct AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, T> {
    static void apply(const vector<T>& vals);
  };

  template <>
  struct AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, char*> {
    static void apply(const vector<char*>& vals);
  };


  template <>
  struct AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, std::string> {
    static void apply(const vector<std::string>& vals);
  };
};
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
namespace myns {
template <typename T>
void MyClass::AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, T>::apply(const vector<T>& vals) {
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_same<T, int16_t>::value ||
                       boost::is_same<T, int32_t>::value ||
                       boost::is_same<T, int64_t>::value));
  // Implementation
}

template <>
void MyClass::AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, char*>::apply(const vector<char*>& vals) {
  // Implementation
}

template <>
void MyClass::AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, std::string>::apply(const vector<std::string>& vals) {
  // Implementation
}
}
```

I believe the compilation error is because full specialization has to be defined at namespace scope, rather than inside the class definition. Beyond this I am lost.

EDIT:
The error message is (roughly) as follows:

```
MyClass.h: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class myns::MyClass’
MyClass.cpp: error: template-id ‘apply<>’ for ‘void myns::MyClass::AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::apply(const vector<std::string>& vals)’ does not match any template declaration
MyClass.cpp: error: invalid function declaration
```

Comment: Done. Sorry for not providing this in the first place. I manually replaced some of the names in the error message with the ones used in the example above (and removed duplicate error messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

MyClass.h:

```
namespace myns {
enum LiteralTypes {
  kINT_LITERAL = 0,
  kSTRING_LITERAL
};

class MyClass {
  template <LiteralTypes literal_type, typename T> struct AddLiterals;

  template <typename T>
  struct AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, T> {
    static void apply(const vector<T>& vals);
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, T> {
    static void apply(const vector<T>& vals);
  };
};
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
namespace myns {
template <typename T>
void MyClass::AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, T>::apply(const vector<T>& vals) {
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_same<T, int16_t>::value ||
                       boost::is_same<T, int32_t>::value ||
                       boost::is_same<T, int64_t>::value));
  // Implementation
}

template <>
void MyClass::AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, char*>::apply(const vector<char*>& vals) {
  // Implementation
}

template <>
void MyClass::AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, std::string>::apply(const vector<std::string>& vals) {
  // Implementation
}
} // namespace myns
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have the answer in your error message: explicit specialization **MUST** be in namespace scope:

Turn your header into this:

```
namespace myns {
enum LiteralTypes {
  kINT_LITERAL = 0,
  kSTRING_LITERAL
};

class MyClass {
  template <LiteralTypes literal_type, typename T> struct AddLiterals;
};

  template <typename T>
  struct MyClass::AddLiterals<kINT_LITERAL, T> {
    static void apply(const vector<T>& vals);
  };

  template <>
  struct MyClass::AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, char*> {
    static void apply(const vector<char*>& vals);
  };


  template <>
  struct MyClass::AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, std::string> {
    static void apply(const vector<std::string>& vals);
  };
}
```

Second, you have a mismatch there, note that you use 2d and 3d specialization with kSTRING_LITERAL in declaration but with kINT_LITERAL in definition

Third, `template<>` not used for a member of a [specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), so omit it in cpp file

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I also need to refactor anything in the .cpp file? By just refactoring the header as described, I get the following error: `MyClass.cpp: error: template-id ‘apply<>’ for ‘void myns::MyClass::AddLiterals<kSTRING_LITERAL, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::apply(const vector<std::string>& vals)’ does not match any template declaration
MyClass.cpp: error: invalid function declaration`